# Include NULLs in MAX() OVER PARTITION

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, window-functions, analytic-functions

I have an Oracle query that I'd like to return a MAX() over a PARTITION while incorporating NULLs.

For instance, if the raw data is:

```
NAME   |  DATE
-----------------------
ADAM   | 01/21/14 00:00
ADAM   | 
ADAM   | 01/22/14 00:01
ADAM   | 01/23/14 00:02
```

Using the following query it returns the following:

```
MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date)
```

```
NAME   |  DATE
-----------------------
ADAM   | 01/21/14 00:00
ADAM   | 01/22/14 00:01
ADAM   | 01/23/14 00:02
ADAM   | 01/23/14 00:02
```

Is it possible to have it act as if the NULLs were a MAX() value so it would return the following?

```
NAME   |  DATE
-----------------------
ADAM   | 01/21/14 00:00
ADAM   | 
ADAM   | 
ADAM   |
```

Comment: Any Aggregate function Ignores `NULL`!(Except `COUNT`), So if you want only `NULL`, need to do `NVL()`

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar These are analytic functions, not aggregate.

Comment: @DavidAldridge yes, still the way the rows are processed only gives place to `NULL`.. `MAX()` would never consider null... Aint I right? WHen `NULLS FIRST` is given.. `MAX(NULL)` would happen first, and it is obviously NULL not `MAX(NULL,'A')` returned a `NULL`..

Comment: @McArthey but what logic you have to make `01/22/13 00:00` as first ?

Comment: Yeah, @MaheswaranRavisankar makes a good point. Your last update makes no sense. Why some rows should get to show NULL as result and others no? Don't you want the same result per `PARTITION BY name`?

Comment: Perhaps my example is flawed but what I'd like to see, basically, is that anything after the NULL will be null'd as if it were the MAX.

Comment: Define ***after***. "After" in what order? SQL tables do not have an inherent order. Rows wil be displayed in arbitrary order - unless you explicitly use `ORDER BY some_expression`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use the analytic function:

```
FIRST_VALUE(date_col) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date_col DESC NULLS FIRST)
```

Test at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6d268/1)**

Comment: I can't guarantee that the NULL will be the FIRST_VALUE.  I have modified my example to represent an example where this wouldn't work.

Comment: The `FIRST_VALUE()` will use the `ORDER BY date_col DESC **NULLS FIRST**`, not the order which you are displaying your data.